# Retrofit response.errorBody.string() gives me warning of inappropriate blocking method call in suspend function

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit2, coroutine

I am developing an Android App.

I am using Retrofit2 and Coroutine to fetch some data from my Rest API.

When there is an exception thrown in my Rest API, it returns exception code and exception message with HTTP status = 4xx or 5xx as per the screenshot below

[image]

If the response is an exception, then I map the exceptionCode and exceptionMessage to the response in my Android app as per the code below.

```
val exceptionBody = Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody()?.string(), ExceptionResponse::class.java)
```

This is `ExceptionResponse` class

```
data class ExceptionResponse(
    val exceptionCode: String,
    val exceptionMessage: String
)
```

Here is a problem. When I do `response.errorBody()?.string()`, Android Studio gives me a warning saying "inappropriate blocking method call"

Here is my `repository` calling the network call

```
override fun fetchData() {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val fetchedData = myRemoteDataSource.fetchData()
    }
}
```

Here is `MyRemoteDataSource` class

```
class MyRemoteDataSourceImpl(
    private val myAPIService: MyAPIService
): BaseRemoteDataSource(), MyRemoteDataSource {

    override suspend fun fetchData(): Resource<List<Data>> {
        return getResult {
            myAPIService.fetchData()
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `BaseRemoteDataSource` class which has the `getResult()` where `errorBody.string` is called

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above, the only coroutine that does not give me the warning is the last one

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody()?.string(), ExceptionResponse::class.java)
}
```

So I have a few questions about this warning and coroutineScope

1. Why the last one does not give me the warning but every other coroutine scopes?

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody()?.string(), ExceptionResponse::class.java)
}
```

2. It seems like I need structured concurrency because I need to parse JSON and return it. If I `CoroutineScope` or `GlobalScope` then I will return null unless I use `scope.join`. Then shouldn't I use coroutineScope() which is using the parent/caller's coroutine scope for structured concurrency?

3. It looks like response.errorBody()?.string() is parsing JSON which is supposed to be in Dispatchers.Default, is not it? Just for your reference, I include the source code for `string()`

```
  public final String string() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedSource source = source()) {
      Charset charset = Util.bomAwareCharset(source, charset());
      return source.readString(charset);
    }
  }
```

4. Is it fine to use the last one because then I am creating GlobalScope in CoroutineScope.

5. does withContext() use caller's coroutine scope just like coroutineScope() or does it create a new scope with different Dispatchers?

Sorry for dumping questios at once but they are all related. Thank you Guys!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normal to call blocking executions in the `IO` context because it is designed to do such tasks. So the best way, I think, is to write an extension function on the `ResponseBody` to do it in the `IO` context appropriately. However, on this function, the warning also appears, but as we know that we handled it well, we can suppress it.

```
@Suppress("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext")
suspend fun ResponseBody.stringSuspending() =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { string() }
```

So we are sure that `ResponseBody.string()` will be executed in `IO` context, no matter it might be wrapped with another context:

```
Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody()?.stringSuspending(), ExceptionResponse::class.java)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. So you are saying that I can just ignore the warning and do the .string() in the current coroutine scope? Then, does it block the whole thread?

Comment: You're welcome :) Suppose that you are calling a block of code containing the `ResponseBody.stringSuspending()` in a `Default` context. Just like: `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) { Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody()?.stringSuspending(), ExceptionResponse::class.java) }`.
When the execution control reaches the `stringSuspending()`, a context switch happens. It means that the current thread would try to execute another code (if any) in the context of `Default`.

Comment: The consequence is that the thread wouldn't be blocked. On the other hand, the `stringSuspending()` will be executed in a thread that is supposed to run `IO` codes. As soon as the execution of `stringSuspending()` gets finished, another context switch happens and the execution will be continued in the `Default` context.

Comment: Bare with my understanding of coroutine and could I ask a few more please? Is there any specific reason to use withContext() rather than coroutineScope() because at the very first, I call the network function in CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) then can I just use coroutineScope() becuase I don't need to switch to different context?

Comment: Sure. We know that the underlying basis of coroutines is thread-management. It's worth noting that each execution should be done in an appropriate context. For example, if you do a CPU-burst job (like sorting a list) in an `IO` context, you're going to wait for its completion more in comparison to `Default` context. `withContext` just assure us that the embraced block of code will be executed in the correct context (in fact, executor thread), with no extra overhead.

Comment: When we build a new coroutine, the default dispatcher which is assigned to it is `Default` if you wouldn't specify directly. (*e.g.* `CoroutineScope().launch { // this block is executed in Default context }`) It is better to use `Default` context always and just switch the context to `IO` or `Main` where it is needed. (just like `stringSuspending` in my answer) This leads to gain maximum performance of coroutines.

Comment: It is interesting to know that libraries like `Room` and `Retrofit` which supports writing `suspend` function, are doing the context switch to `IO` in their generated codes. So, there is no need to launch your coroutines in `IO` context. A very useful doc is here that could answer most of your questions: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines-adv

Comment: thank you very much for the reference and your answers